# Spring Mass System DE $my''+\beta y'+ky=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation for a spring mass system 
$$my''+\beta y'+ky=0$$
I have to find the displacement $y$ at any time $t$. $\beta =2\sqrt{mk}$ and the initial conditions are $y(0)=h>0$ and $y'(0)=v$. I initally found the following
$$y=(a+bt)e^\frac{-t\sqrt{mk}}{m}$$
I am currently stuck with the initial conditions as I end up with $b=\frac{-v\sqrt{mk}}{ak}$ from  $y'(0)=v$ and I don't know how to interpret $y(0)=h>0$

**EDIT**: I now have $$y=(h+v+ht\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})e^\frac{-t\sqrt{mk}}{m}$$

and have to express y=0 as an inequality $v<-f(h,k,m)$ for the function $f$

Comment: Is $\beta =2\sqrt{mk}$ assumption?

Comment: @MyGlasses It states 'Suppose $\beta =2\sqrt{mk}$, so that the system experiences critical damping'

Comment: $y(0)=h$ says $a=h$.

Comment: $y'(0)=v$ says $b=v+h\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, right?

Comment: @MyGlasses I'm getting $b=v+\frac{hk}{\sqrt{mk}}$ and is $y(0)=h>0$ just saying $y(0)=h$ and $h>0$?

Comment: @JeanMarie That link doesn't work

Comment: See MIT OCW( open courseware) on spring mass system in the case of overdamping.

Comment: @MyGlasses Is that what $y(0)=h>0$ is saying?

Comment: I think so.....

Comment: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}y= \lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{h+t(v+h\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})}{e^{t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}}= \lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{v+h\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}e^{t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}}\to0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\left(h+t(v+h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}})\right)e^\frac{-t\sqrt{mk}}{m}=0$$
then $h+t(v+h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}})=0$ or 
$$t=-\dfrac{h}{v+h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}}>0$$
with $h>0$ sould be $v+h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}<0$ or $v<-h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}=-f(h,k,m)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, why is $t=-\dfrac{v+h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}}{h}>0$, I seem to get $t=-\dfrac{h}{v+h\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}}>0$

Comment: time can't  be negative